# In Xcode 7 how can I have a static lib target and a framework target with the same name?

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, xcode7, carthage

I'm trying to convert an existing GitHub repo ([RMStore](https://github.com/robotmedia/RMStore), but it could apply to any repo) to be compatible with [Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage). This requires adding a Framework target to the Xcode Project. I want the resulting framework to be called `RMStore.framework`, however I cannot create a new target to the Xcode project called **RMStore** because there is already a target with that name, which builds a static library (and I don't want to get rid of that target).

I created a new target called **RMStoreFramework**, but the resulting framework is called `RMStoreFramework.framework`, which is not what I want.
So, is there a way to either:

1. create two targets with the same name or alternatively,
2. make the name of the resulting framework be different to the target name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the name of resulting framework. On *Build Settings* -> *Product Name*, you can choose the name that you want.

This pattern can be seen in projects that support Carthage and support both iOS and Mac platforms.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I can't believe it was that simple!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't try my self but I think you can change the resulting framework be different to a different name from script.
[image]

Comment: which script is this?